# How can I use python to convert multiple date columns into one date column and sum up their values (example below)?

Tags: python

Following is the table I have -

```
Market  05-20  06-20  07-20  08-20

HK      5      5      5      5

US      2      2      2      2

HK      3      3      3      3

UK      7      7      7      7

UK      2      2      2      2
```

Follwoing is what I want to make of it -

```
Market  Date       Quantity

HK      05-20      8    

HK      06-20      8 

HK      07-20      8 

HK      08-20      8

US      05-20      2    

US      06-20      2

US      07-20      2    

US      08-20      2

UK      05-20      9 

UK      06-20      9  

UK      07-20      9 

UK      08-20      9
```

How can I use python to convert multiple date columns into one date column and sum up their values (example below)?

Comment: Need more info. Where is your code? What library are you using? Show us something

Comment: What are the values you want to sum up?  Is it the total for each Market?

Comment: first you could `groupby("Market")` and `sum()` values in every group. And next probably you would have to `pivot` table.

Answer (score 1):

First you can use

```
 df = df.groupby("Market").sum()
```

Result:

```
        05-20  06-20  07-20  08-20
Market                            
HK          8      8      8      8
UK          9      9      9      9
US          2      2      2      2
```

Next you can

```
df = df.stack()
```

Result:

```
Market       
HK      05-20    8
        06-20    8
        07-20    8
        08-20    8
UK      05-20    9
        06-20    9
        07-20    9
        08-20    9
US      05-20    2
        06-20    2
        07-20    2
        08-20    2
```

Now you have to only `reset_index()`,  and add column names.

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = ['Market', 'Data', 'Quantity']
```

Result:

```
    Market   Data  Quantity
0      HK  05-20         8
1      HK  06-20         8
2      HK  07-20         8
3      HK  08-20         8
4      UK  05-20         9
5      UK  06-20         9
6      UK  07-20         9
7      UK  08-20         9
8      US  05-20         2
9      US  06-20         2
10     US  07-20         2
11     US  08-20         2
```

---

Full example code. I use `io>StringIO` only to simulate file.

```
text ='''Market  05-20  06-20  07-20  08-20
HK      5      5      5      5
US      2      2      2      2
HK      3      3      3      3
UK      7      7      7      7
UK      2      2      2      2'''

import pandas as pd
import io

#df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep="\s+")

df = df.groupby("Market").sum()
print(df)

df = df.stack()
print(df)

df = df.reset_index()
print(df)

df.columns = ['Market', 'Data', 'Quantity']
print(df)
```